# Can't install a Python package

Tags: python, installation, centos

I'm very new to CentOS and I am trying to install the M2Crypto Python package on it.

I ran:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

And it appeared to go ok: (this is the end of the output)

```
removing 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing M2Crypto-0.20.2-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
Removing /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto-0.20.2-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
Copying M2Crypto-0.20.2-py2.4-linux-i686.egg to /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages
M2Crypto 0.20.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto-0.20.2-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
Processing dependencies for M2Crypto==0.20.2
```

However I can't import M2Crypto:

```
$ python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Nov 11 2010, 13:34:43) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import M2Crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
File "M2Crypto/__init__.py", line 22, in ?
import __m2crypto
ImportError: No module named __m2crypto
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are doing anything wrong. I installed the package with apt on Ubuntu, and have no problems with Python 2.6. (Why are you using v2.4 of Python?) The module is being loaded from /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/M2Crypto where there is a __m2crypto.so file. I found another copy of M2Crypto in /usr/share/pyshared/M2Crypto, and there are no .so files there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Apalala. I running Python 2.4 because that's the default with CentOS and a lot of the CentOS tools expect Python 2.4 from what I've read. The M2Crypto docs say that it does run with 2.4.

Comment: You can always install a newer version of python (by default into /usr/local/bin/) and have your scripts reference the Python at that path. That way you can have separate module directories for your system python vs. your development/deployment python. When you configure your python source just set --prefix=/usr/local/ (which it does by default, but.. you can make it whatever you want..)

Answer (score 6):

I ran:

```
python setup.py tests
```

and that fixed it. It copied some files, which I think resulted in the lib being put in the right place.

```
running test
running egg_info
writing M2Crypto.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to M2Crypto.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to M2Crypto.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.4/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so -> M2Crypto
test_BitSTring (tests.test_asn1.ASN1TestCase) ... ok
.
.
.
```

Comment: +1! As you said, running "setup.py test" fixed the installation problem on CentOS as well!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`tests` isn't a valid target, run `test` instead; that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue, on centos 6.2.

Running test also fixed it for me. However when I looked in site packages, nothing was changed. Running setup.py test builds m2crpyto in the local directory.

That's the key to the problem, to fix the issue without running setup.py test, leave the M2Crypto folder. It's picking up m2crypto from the local folder, and not finding the egg.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me occasionally when installing python modules.  There are a couple of things I do to resolve this issue:

1. Sometimes it's because you never set your PYTHONPATH.  Try:

   > setenv PYTHONPATH
   >   /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
2. Sometimes it's because of shared libraries found in /usr/lib and you would have to perform:

> setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Let me know how this goes for you.  Most of the time its just because you didn't set the python  path correctly.